# Reducing matrix rows or columns in CUDA

Tags: cuda, cublas

I'm using CUDA with `cuBLAS` to perform matrix operations.

I need to sum the rows (or columns) of a matrix. Currently I'm doing it by multiplying the matrix with a ones vector but this doesn't seem so efficient.

Is there any better way? Couldn't find anything in `cuBLAS`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312228/cuda-add-rows-of-a-matrix might help. However, if you only need it "sometimes", i.e. it doesn't take up a significant percentage of your run time, I'd say that your method is perfectly acceptable, even though it incurrs the overhead of all those extra multiplications...

Comment: But anyways, this is quite an easy kernel to implement yourself. Have a look at the example from this CalState presentation on CUDA:  http://www.calstatela.edu/faculty/rpamula/cs370/GPUProgramming.pptx

Comment: "sometimes" wasn't a good word. I do it as a part of training a neural network so it runs iteratively many times. The example code in the ppts doesn't work.. (the parameter is a pointer and it tries to access it like a 2D array).

Comment: It's not that hard to modify though, right? It depends on the layout of your matrix in memory anyways, depending on whether you have row-major or column-major storage and whether you use padding.

Comment: Compared to the matrix-matrix multiplication operation, row-sum takes only tiny portion of time of training neural networks. You can ignore it I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually multiplying the matrix with a ones vector using `cublas_gemv()` is a very efficient way, unless you are considering write your own kernel by hand.

You can easily profile the mem bandwidth of `cublas_gemv()`. It's very close to that of simply reading the whole matrix data once, which can be seen as the theoretical peak performance of matrix row/col summation.

The extra operation "x1.0" won't lead to much performance reduction because:

1. `cublas_gemv()` is basically a mem bandwidth bound operation, extra arithmetic instructions won't be the bottleneck;
2. [FMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fused_multiply%E2%80%93add) instruction further reduce the instruction throughput;
3. mem of ones vector is usually much smaller than that of the matrix, and can be easily cache by GPU to reduce to mem bandwidth.

`cublas_gemv()` also help you deal with the matrix layout problem. It works on row/col-major and arbitrary padding.

I also asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211093/how-to-normalize-matrix-columns-in-cuda-with-max-performance) about this. My experiment shows `cublas_gemv()` is better than segmented reduce using `Thrust::reduce_by_key`, which is another approach of matrix row summation.

Comment: Makes sense. I was using gemm for that, for some reason. :) thanks.

Comment: @Ran, my test shows `cublas_gemv` is 2x faster than `cublas_gemm` for this operation. the size of the test matrix is 3000 x 3000.

Answer (score 1):

Posts related to this one containing useful answers on the same topic are available at

[Reduce matrix rows with CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862078/reduce-matrix-rows-with-cuda)

and

[Reduce matrix columns with CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428378/reduce-matrix-columns-with-cuda).

Here I just want to point out how the approach of reducing the columns of a matrix through the multiplication of a row by the same matrix can be generalized to perform the **linear combination** of an ensemble of vectors. In other words, if one wants to calculate the following **vector basis expansion**

[image]

where `f(x_m)` are samples of the function `f(x)`, while the `\psi_n`'s are basis functions and the `c_n`'s are expansion coefficients, then the `\psi_n`'s can be organized in a `N x M` matrix and the coefficients `c_n`'s in a row vector and then compute the vector x matrix multiplication using `cublas<t>gemv`.

Below, I'm reporting a fully worked example:

```
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

/********************************************/
/* LINEAR COMBINATION FUNCTION - FLOAT CASE */
/********************************************/
void linearCombination(const float * __restrict__ d_coeff, const float * __restrict__ d_basis_functions_real, float * __restrict__ d_linear_combination,
                       const int N_basis_functions, const int N_sampling_points, const cublasHandle_t handle) {

    float alpha = 1.f;
    float beta  = 0.f;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, N_sampling_points, N_basis_functions, &alpha, d_basis_functions_real, N_sampling_points, 
                               d_coeff, 1, &beta, d_linear_combination, 1));

}

void linearCombination(const double * __restrict__ d_coeff, const double * __restrict__ d_basis_functions_real, double * __restrict__ d_linear_combination,
                       const int N_basis_functions, const int N_sampling_points, const cublasHandle_t handle) {

    double alpha = 1.;
    double beta  = 0.;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasDgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, N_sampling_points, N_basis_functions, &alpha, d_basis_functions_real, N_sampling_points, 
                               d_coeff, 1, &beta, d_linear_combination, 1));

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int N_basis_functions = 5;     // --- Number of rows                  -> Number of basis functions
    const int N_sampling_points = 8;     // --- Number of columns               -> Number of sampling points of the basis functions

    // --- Random uniform integer distribution between 10 and 99
    thrust::default_random_engine rng;
    thrust::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(10, 99);

    // --- Matrix allocation and initialization
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_basis_functions_real(N_basis_functions * N_sampling_points);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_basis_functions_real.size(); i++) d_basis_functions_real[i] = (float)dist(rng);

    thrust::device_vector<double> d_basis_functions_double_real(N_basis_functions * N_sampling_points);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_basis_functions_double_real.size(); i++) d_basis_functions_double_real[i] = (double)dist(rng);

    /************************************/
    /* COMPUTING THE LINEAR COMBINATION */
    /************************************/
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasCreate(&handle));

    thrust::device_vector<float>  d_linear_combination_real(N_sampling_points);
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_linear_combination_double_real(N_sampling_points);
    thrust::device_vector<float>  d_coeff_real(N_basis_functions, 1.f);
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_coeff_double_real(N_basis_functions, 1.);

    linearCombination(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_coeff_real.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_basis_functions_real.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_linear_combination_real.data()),
                      N_basis_functions, N_sampling_points, handle);
    linearCombination(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_coeff_double_real.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_basis_functions_double_real.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_linear_combination_double_real.data()),
                      N_basis_functions, N_sampling_points, handle);

    /*************************/
    /* DISPLAYING THE RESULT */
    /*************************/
    std::cout << "Real case \n\n";
    for(int j = 0; j < N_sampling_points; j++) {
        std::cout << "Column " << j << " - [ ";
        for(int i = 0; i < N_basis_functions; i++)
            std::cout << d_basis_functions_real[i * N_sampling_points + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "] = " << d_linear_combination_real[j] << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\n\nDouble real case \n\n";
    for(int j = 0; j < N_sampling_points; j++) {
        std::cout << "Column " << j << " - [ ";
        for(int i = 0; i < N_basis_functions; i++)
            std::cout << d_basis_functions_double_real[i * N_sampling_points + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "] = " << d_linear_combination_double_real[j] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is "Utilities.cuh"? is it included in cublas or thrust?

Comment: @TejusPrasad You can find it at this [github repository](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/CUDA-Utilities).